# How to compute integrals of functions of Brownian Motion with respect to time and Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

How are functions of Brownian Motion integrated with respect to time? For example, how to calculate the integral:
$$I_1 = \int_0^t \lvert \cos(B(s)) \rvert^2 \; ds $$

Secondly, how would an integral such as $I_2$ be calculated:
$$I_2 = \int_0^t \lvert \cos(B(s)) \rvert^2 \; dB(s) $$

Finally, in general what is the approach to calculating integrals of the type:
$$I_3 = \int_0^t f(B(s))\; ds $$
and
$$I_4 = \int_0^t f(B(s)) \; dB(s) $$

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot "compute" integrals involving Brownian motion in a traditional sense as these integrals are not numbers, but rather random variables. So, typically, the best you can hope for is to find their distributions.

- The easiest case is when you consider non-random function $f(t)$ and you integrate it w.r.t. a Brownian motion, $B_t$. In that case, it is easy to show from the definition that
  \begin{equation}
  \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \sim N\left(0,\int_0^t|f(s)|^2ds\right)
  \end{equation}
- An integral of the form $\int_0^tf(B_s)ds$ can be "computed" just like a standard integral using Riemann sums.
- For more general integrals we can try to use Ito's Lemma to transform the original integral into something more manageable. Ito's Lemma, in it simplest form, tells us that
  \begin{equation}
  f(B_t) = f(B_0) + \int_0^t f'(B_s)dB_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf''(B_s)ds
  \end{equation}
  under suitable conditions on $f$. For example, using the above formula we can easily see that $\int_0^tB_sdB_s = 1/2B_t^2 - 1/2t$.

Comment: So both integrals of functions of random variables with respect to $d \,B_s$ and $ds$ end up being random variables and the best we can hope for is to find their distributions?

Comment: That's right. Sometimes you can simplify them (as in the case of $\int_0^t B_s d B_s$) but you are still dealing with a random variable.